# loop over 2^n states of n bits in C with n > 32

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'd like to have a loop in C over all possible 2^n states of n bits. For example if n=4 I'd like to loop over 0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, ..., 1110, 1111. The bits can be represented in any way, for example an integer array of length n with values 0 or 1, or a character array of length n with values "0" or "1", etc, it doesn't really matter.

For smallish n what I do is calculate x=2^n using integer arithmetic (both n and x are integers), then

```
for(i=0;i<x;i++) {
    bits = convert_integer_to_bits( i );
    work_on_bits( bits );
}
```

Here 'bits' is in the given representation of bits, what was useful so far is an integer array of length n with values 0 or 1 (but can be anything else).

If n>32 this approach obviously doesn't work even with longs.

How would I work with n>32?

Specifically, do I really need to evaluate 2^n, or is there a tricky way of writing the loop which does not refer to the actual value of 2^n but nevertheless iterates 2^n times?

Comment: #include <stdint.h>

int32_t my_32bit_int; which can declare a 32 bit integer

Comment: Use a `uint64_t`. When you're done iterating over all its values, come back and post a second question.

Comment: _All_ integers have their bits in them. To get bit `n` of _any_ integer you use `i & (1 << n)`. You don't need to "convert integer to bits".

Comment: Does this work if i is of type uint64_t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For n > 32 use `unsigned long long`. This will work for n up to 64. Still for values even close to 50 you will have to wait **long** time until the cycle finishes.

Comment: But sizeof( unsigned long long ) is the same as sizeof( long ) so how would that help?

Comment: unsigned long long is 64 bit on all compilers I have seen, long on the other hand may be 32 or 64 depending on the compiler and the architecture. Also keep in mind that you will have to take the bits a bit differently. For instance `unsigned long long a =1; a&(1ULL<<55);` Notice the ULL after the 1.

Comment: Thanks, this last part is not yet clear. How do I get bit x of an unsigned long long variable y?

Comment: @Daniel you need to perform bit operations on a unsigned long long number. So use `(a&(1ULL<<50))` to check the 50-th bit. If you write only `1<<50`(without ULL) this will not work as compiler will assume 1 is integer.

Comment: But 50 is okay? It doesn't need to be 50ULL?

Comment: And this is what is not clear: a & ( 1ULL << n ) gives me stuff which is not always only 0 or 1 (sometimes larger), how can that be for a bit?

Comment: @Daniel no it doesn't need to be `50ULL` you always shift a number with an integer(and for `unsigned long long` you never shift with more than 64 so that should be fine). For your second question - the value of a&(1ULL<<50) is zero if the corresponding bit is 0 and non-zero(in fact 1ULL<<50 or `2^50`) if the bit is 1. Try reading a bit more on bit operations.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you say that if n>32, it *obviously* won't work. Is your concern the width of bits, or is your concern the run time?

If you're concerned about number width, investigate a big math library such as http://gmplib.org/.

If you're concerned about run time... you won't live long enough for your loop to complete if the width is large enough, so get a different hobby ;)   Seriously... figure out the rough run time of one iteration through your loop and multiply that by 4 billion, divide by 20 years, and you'll have an estimate of the number of generations of your ancestors that will need to wait for the answer.

Comment: If n>32 my method doesn't work because I use integer (or long) arithmetic. If n>32 the result from 2^n (in integer or long arithmetic) will be garbage.

Comment: @Daniel simply use unsigned long long as indicated in my answer

Comment: @Daniel, that's why I suggested using a big math library. Using one, you won't be using any scalar type -- and then you won't be locked in to a max of 64 bit width. Regardless, you won't have enough time to iterate through 32 bits using modern CPUs.